# Git: some files removed every commit

Tags: git, gitignore

Every time I'm committing my changes to Git repo (Github if any) 3 files from **any** branch are marked as deleted.

I've tried to copy these 3 files from `master`, and adding them with `git add` to my branch.

After performing a pull request, and creating a new branch, this strange thing happen again.
According to the history files were never deleted.

The missing files are Qt translation (*.ts), and have an XML-like format.

There is no `*.ts` in .gitignore

EDIT: `git version 2.16.2.windows.1`

EDIT: Sharing `.gitignore` to be sure

```
# Compiled Object files
*.slo
*.lo
*.o
*.obj

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch
*.pch

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so
*.dylib
*.dll

# Fortran module files
*.mod

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai
*.la
*.a
*.lib

# Executables
*.exe
*.out
*.app
```

EDIT
Commit command and output looks like

```
git commit --all -m"#ISSUE_NUMBER fix typo"
 4 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 377 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 
translations/app_texts.ts
```

I did not deleted *.ts file

EDIT
Still did not solve the problem, but isolated it. It appears only on one laptop, and does not depend on Git version (files keep being removed even after update Git). Renaming directory with *.ts files did not help as well. I just do not commit on this laptop anymore, but the nature of the problem is completely unclear, I'm ready to download Git sources and do some debugging

Comment: Can you share your `.gitignore`, just to be on the safe side? Also, is it possible you have a git hook that may be involved?

Comment: I didn't understand this statement. _I'm thinking and something talking some obscenities and copy these 3 files from master, and adding with git add_ Could you clarify ?

Comment: Let's say, I'm working in a #ISSUE-NUMBER branch. I'm executing git commit --all -m"msg". 3 files are marked as deleted. I'm copying them from master branch, adding, committing again, pushing

Nope, only *.sample files in .git/hooks

Comment: You mean they show up as deleted in `git status` after commit?

Comment: I mean after git commit list of changes is displayed - added, edited, deleted

Comment: Please show command ran and output.

Comment: Sure, as soon as I reproduce

Comment: With some small edits unable to reproduce the issue (really not sure size of commit is the reason), but changing 1-2 rows works fine

Comment: Are the files manually written or are they generated as a part of the build process? Maybe there could be some "make clean" command or similar which removes those files, if they are generated...

Comment: I was thinking about that. They are partly composed automatically, but do not created again, just content is being changed. Also, re-generation does not connected to it's disappearance (one of them has not been changed for a year)

Comment: The `--all` certainly causes Git to pick up any changes done locally by ... anything. Do you have an anti-virus system which deletes files when you are not watching, for example?

Comment: Since the issue appears only on one machine, it may be specific to it. My tip is that a global `.gitignore`file is set on that machine: check the output of `git config core.excludesFile` and if the file is set, then maybe it contains `*.ts`.

Comment: @tripleee This is an interesting theory, but I can not imagine why my antivirus should delete *.ts files. By the way, last time it deleted also *.mc file, that's why I stopped using this system for a while, and I tend to think it was deleted by "something else"

Comment: The obvious workaround is to not use `--all` and instead tell `git` exactly what to commit.

Comment: Exactly, but this does not solve the problem of "something" which deletes source files (Avast found nothing suspicious). Anyway, problem is not Git

Answer (score 0):

Git appeared to be not a reason of the issue. Files are being deleted during CMake processing. Qt+CMake compatibility issues are not something new, [this one for example](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31860?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true). Using `--all` Git key picking up this changes. Quick solution in this case just observing every commit, if it happens on regular basis it's a reason to report a bug and/or do change (upgrade, downgrade) CMake